# OpenLiteSpeed rewrite rules with CyberPanel

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to transfer my site from a shared cpanel host to my own VPS running Cyberpanel and OLS, this issue I am having is I cant get rewrites to work what-so-ever.

Any help would be appreciated as this has been doing my head in for the last 2 days/

Here is the .htaccess file I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 403 /assets/error/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error/500.html

# Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Global URL
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/x/([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=$1&x=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/edit/([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=$1&edit=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/delete/([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=$1&delete=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/recover/([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=$1&recover=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/activate/([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=$1&activate=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/x/([^/]*)/y/([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=$1&x=$2&y=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^offerwall/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /offerwall.php?key=$1&sub_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^lead/status/([^/]*)$ /lead.php?status=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^lead/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /lead.php?hash=$1&key=$2&sid=$3&token=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^go/([^/]*)$ /offer.php?key=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^shortlink/load/([^/]*)$ /redirect.php?load=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^shortlink/result/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /shortlink.php?short_key=$1&sub_id=$2&site_id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^shortlink/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /redirect.php?api=$1&sub_id=$2&short_id=$3&token=$4 [L]

# Publisher URL
RewriteRule ^publisher.html$ /publisher.php [L]
RewriteRule ^publisher/([^/]*)\.html$ /publisher.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^publisher/([^/]*)/x/([^/]*)\.html$ /publisher.php?page=$1&x=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^publisher/([^/]*)/edit/([^/]*)\.html$ /publisher.php?page=$1&edit=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^publisher/([^/]*)/delete/([^/]*)\.html$ /publisher.php?page=$1&delete=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^publisher/([^/]*)/x/([^/]*)/y/([^/]*)\.html$ /publisher.php?page=$1&x=$2&y=$3 [L]

# Advertiser URL
RewriteRule ^advertiser.html$ /advertiser.php [L]
RewriteRule ^advertiser/([^/]*)\.html$ /advertiser.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^advertiser/([^/]*)/x/([^/]*)\.html$ /advertiser.php?page=$1&x=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^advertiser/([^/]*)/edit/([^/]*)\.html$ /advertiser.php?page=$1&edit=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^advertiser/([^/]*)/delete/([^/]*)\.html$ /advertiser.php?page=$1&delete=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^advertiser/([^/]*)/x/([^/]*)/y/([^/]*)\.html$ /advertiser.php?page=$1&x=$2&y=$3 [L]

# Admin Rewrite
RewriteRule ^admin.html$ /admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)\.html$ /admin.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/x/([^/]*)\.html$ /admin.php?page=$1&x=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/x/([^/]*)/y/([^/]*)\.html$ /admin.php?page=$1&x=$2&y=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/edit/([^/]*)\.html$ /admin.php?page=$1&edit=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/delete/([^/]*)\.html$ /admin.php?page=$1&delete=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/pay/([^/]*)\.html$ /admin.php?page=$1&pay=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/mark/([^/]*)\.html$ /admin.php?page=$1&mark=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/reject/([^/]*)\.html$ /admin.php?page=$1&reject=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/confirm/([^/]*)\.html$ /admin.php?page=$1&confirm=$2 [L]

# Protect .htaccess
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    # Enable Keep Alive
    Header set Connection keep-alive
    
    # Properly handle requests coming from behind proxies
    Header append Vary User-Agent
    
    # Turn on Expires
    ExpiresActive On
    
    # Turn off ETag
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
        Header unset ETag
        FileETag None
    </FilesMatch>

    # Set up caching on media files for 5 weeks
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf|flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)$">
        ExpiresDefault A3024000
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </FilesMatch>
     
    # Set up 7 days caching on commonly updated files
    <FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
        ExpiresDefault A604800
        Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
     
    # Force no caching for dynamic files
    <FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl|htm)$">
        ExpiresActive Off
        Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    </FilesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

I have followed all guides online but nothing works, here is the site: https://offerwall.offers4crypto.xyz/

Comment: "I cant get rewrites to work" - It doesn't look like your `.htaccess` file is being processed at all!? Your custom 404 is not being set and `.woff2` files are being sent with a `max-age=604800` Cache-Control header (it should be `3024000` according to your rules). On Apache you would need to set `AllowOverride All` (or similar) in the server config to essentially "enable" `.htaccess` file processing (not sure if the same applies to OLS). But apparently on OLS you will need to restart OLS after making any changes to `.htaccess` - since it is only processed on start-up. (?)